# can't update query in my db ,getting the error about updateable query

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic, sql-update, insert-update

i am tring to update but id didn't work ....

' Database connection - remember to specify the path to your database

```
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")         
Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("dbbb.mdb")

' Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
 Dim strSQL     

strSQL = "INSERT INTO people ("

strSQL = strSQL & "firstName , "
strSQL = strSQL & "lastName , "

strSQL = strSQL & "phone , "
strSQL = strSQL & "birthDate ) "

strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES("

strSQL = strSQL & "'Cousin', "

strSQL = strSQL & "'Gus', "
strSQL = strSQL & "'99887766', "

strSQL = strSQL & "'20-04-1964')"

' The SQL statement is executed 
Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)

' Close the database connection
  rs.Close()
Set rs = Nothing
Conn.Close()
Set Conn = Nothing
```

I am getting the error

Operation must use an updateable query.

I must missed a space or something.... what can be the problem I seccuseed to read from the db but I can't update)

Comment: Do the regional settings of the machine hosting the database support the DD-MM-YYYY notation?  I'm concerned the date isn't being handled correctly.  Additionally, I'm not sure if the jet provider should be using # for the dates or '

Comment: Perhaps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/119bb57a-4082-4be8-aaf6-1ce2efd1d02e/access-does-not-support-oledbparameter-datetime?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: I'd suggest not creating a recordset when you're simply executing an insert. It's unnecessary. You can simply execute on the connection with no object assignment. So your statement would then be Conn.Execute strSQL instead of Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL). (See http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_add.asp) Even if that doesn't address the error directly, it's a better way to operate in this case.

Comment: IT IS KINDA PRACTICE FOR ME FOR I AM A NEW IN THIS ASP AND DB HANDLER FIELD. SO I WANT TO SEE THE RESULT HAPPENING AND THAT WHY I AM NOT EXECUTE ON THE CONNECTION :)

Comment: check this : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175168

Comment: Might be worth trying # for date delimiters and ANSI date format as suggested by xQbert `strSQL = strSQL & "#1964-04-20#)"`

Answer (score 0):

Do Not ever use "Execute" method to insert.
User ADODB.RecordSet Instead

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("dbbb.mdb")
Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Rs.Open "Select Top 1 * From people", Conn,3,3
   Rs.AddNew
   Rs("firstName") = 'Cousin'
   Rs("lastName") = 'Gus'
   Rs("phone") = '99887766'
   Rs("lastName") = CDate('20-04-1964')
   Rs.Update
   Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
```

Comment: "Do Not ever use "Execute" method to insert"... Why not? Your example requires 2 database queries, where as an update query using Execute results in only 1 query.

Comment: I have bad experience with execute command to update data.. specially when update date/time data. With adodb recordset that problem solved.

Comment: Both methods are prone to error writing. If you create a function to format dates to a SQL friendly format ("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm") you won't have any problems with dates. I have functions to format strings for SQL (add single quotes, escape single quotes), numbers (force numeric) and other data types as required. These also ensure I avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Wow you are expert... I am just a beginner.. So I choose the simple method and simple function vbscript. CDate, CCur, Cint, Clng and else. But Please give us your function.. So I can copied to my codes.. as a reference of my knowledge..

Comment: i could use a code corrected by you if you could post it . thanks

Comment: For some example functions see http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/749/classic-asp-functions-for-database-queries-and-sql-injection-protection/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the folder that your database is in does not have write permissions enabled for the user the website is running under.

Usually you need to give the user IUSR_ or IUSR read/write permissions to the MDB file or folder it is in. The user can vary depending on operating system/IIS versions/IIS settings.

If you provide some more details about your hosting environment we may be able to help further (eg. local or cliud, IIS version, control panel access, etc).

Comment: i had  i previous question where i was able to read so from what i understand i do have the permissions :)

Comment: By default the database MDB file will only have READ permission. But to do an UPDATE you also need WRITE permission. This really is the most likely problem for this error message.

Comment: i spoke with the server support and they said i have all the permission :(

Comment: If you can read from the database but not write (and the query is ok) then I still think it is permissions related. Try writing a asp script to create a text file in the same folder (eg. http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_createtextfile_folder.asp). If that doesn't work then you definately have a permissions error.

Comment: apparently you were right :) permission problem ....the feeling when i found out :((